# Aschbacher classes for compact simple group

Tags: group-theory, finite-groups, representation-theory, lie-groups

Aschbacher's theorem says that every maximal subgroup of a finite simple classical group falls into at least one of the 9 Aschbacher classes.

Is there a similar result for compact simple classical groups?

That is, do all finite subgroups of compact simple classical groups fall into one of the 9 Aschbacher classes?

Motivation: This paper https://arxiv.org/pdf/math/0502080.pdf seems to use some sort of Aschbacher's theorem for complex matrix groups in the discussion about prop 1.2 (top of page 2).

Is this one of those situations where representation theory of finite groups over a field of characteristic not dividing $ |G| $ is equivalent to representation theory over a field of characteristic $ 0 $? So the representation theory for finite groups actually encompasses the representation theory over $ \mathbb{R} $ and $ \mathbb{C} $?